# Custom Notification from Auth0 to iOS

Tags: ios7, auth0

I have an iOS 7 iPad app that uses Auth0 to authenticate users. Auth0 sends a verification message to each new user's email address to verify the email address. I would like my app to be informed when the email address has been verified. I have not found a way to do this without repeatedly querying Auth0 for the user's profile until the profile indicates the email address is verified.

Has anyone found a more efficient way to do this? I am very new to process communication over the internet, but I see that I may be able to use an Auth0 Rule to send a URL get request. I also see that I have added URL schemes to my app to enable it to respond to URLs. But I don't know if these two features can be used to provide a notification from Auth0 to a device that the event I want has occurred.

Has anyone a solution to this?